# Need Help in extended events SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, performance, extended-events, performance-tuning, query-performance

I have created an extended event as below. I want to know how to query the historical data using T-SQL to see the issues at particular timestamps. The trace is running as of now

```
CREATE EVENT SESSION [PerQuerymonitor] ON SERVER 
ADD EVENT sqlos.wait_info(
    ACTION(sqlserver.database_name,sqlserver.plan_handle,sqlserver.sql_text)),
ADD EVENT sqlos.wait_info_external(
    ACTION(sqlserver.database_name,sqlserver.plan_handle,sqlserver.sql_text)),
ADD EVENT sqlserver.disk_log_read(
    ACTION(sqlserver.database_name,sqlserver.plan_handle,sqlserver.sql_text)),
ADD EVENT sqlserver.sql_batch_completed(SET collect_batch_text=(1)
    ACTION(sqlserver.database_name,sqlserver.plan_handle,sqlserver.sql_text)),
ADD EVENT sqlserver.sql_batch_starting(
    ACTION(sqlserver.database_name,sqlserver.plan_handle,sqlserver.sql_text)),
ADD EVENT sqlserver.sql_statement_completed(
    ACTION(sqlserver.database_name,sqlserver.plan_handle,sqlserver.sql_text)),
ADD EVENT sqlserver.sql_statement_starting(
    ACTION(sqlserver.database_name,sqlserver.plan_handle,sqlserver.sql_text)) 
ADD TARGET package0.event_file
(SET filename=N'C:\SQLDatabase\PerQuerymonitor.xel',
max_file_size=(204800))
WITH (MAX_MEMORY=4096 KB,
EVENT_RETENTION_MODE=ALLOW_SINGLE_EVENT_LOSS,MAX_DISPATCH_LATENCY=30 SECONDS,MAX_EVENT_SIZE=0 KB,MEMORY_PARTITION_MODE=NONE,TRACK_CAUSALITY=OFF,STARTUP_STATE=ON)
GO
```

Appreciate your kind help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of this Stack Overflow question - [How to read extended events .xel file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53147992/how-to-read-extended-events-xel-file)

Answer (score 0):

This isn't answering your question, but please be careful with extended events.  This one has no filters on it at all, so it's collecting a lot of data.  If this is run on a small test box then you won't know and won't care.  If you ran this on a highly transactional production system then there's a good chance your users would be able to tell you that something bad is happening.

If you want to know more about extended events read Jonathan Kehayias's work.

https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/jonathan/an-xevent-a-day-31-days-of-extended-events/

If you have a PluralSight subscription he and his coworker Erin Stellato have some great videos teaching you a lot more on this subject.